# Get active language store OpenCart

Tags: php, function, opencart

I am building a web export to OpenCart. I want to get the lanuage(s). I already have an export to Magento. With Magento we did it like this:

```
function getLanguages() {
        $langs = "";
        $languages = Mage::app()->getStores();
        foreach ($languages as $language) {
            if ($language->getIsActive()) {
                $lang = array();
                $lang["lang_id"] = $language->getStoreId();
                $lang["name"] = $language->getName();
                $langs[] = $lang;
            }
        }

        return $langs;
}
```

Is there a similar way to make this function in OpenCart? I still do not know how I should / will do it. So all the help is welcome. If you don't know how to do this, but you know which functions i can use. Then i also like to hear it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to use the Localisation\Language modal, this contains the function "getLanguages()" and returns all the active languages.

**Example:**

```
$this->load->modal('localisation/language');
$languages = $this->{'model_localisation_language'}->getLanguages();
```

Comment: Thanks. I think i can get the store id with this code: $this->config->get('config_store_id')? and do you know a similar functor for the $language->getName(); function?

Comment: @StefWinter foreach the $languages variable and use the 'name' value in the arrays. You can find the language_id and code the same way.

Comment: Like this: foreach ($languages as $language) {
         $lang = array();
            $lang["lang_id"] =  $this->config->get('config_store_id');
            $lang["name"] =  $this->config->get('name');
            $langs[] = $lang;
        } ?

Comment: @StefWinter No, you need to use "$language['language_id']" and "$language['name']" not configuration values.

Comment: So, just for sure, it have to be like this: $langs = "";
        foreach ($languages as $language) {
         $lang = array();
            $lang["lang_id"] =  $language['language_id'];
            $lang["name"] =  $language['name'];
            $langs[] = $lang;
        } ?

Comment: @StefWinter I think so.